# Переопределение базового класса User

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Создаю свой класс `User` по примеру из [официальной документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user)
Вот код:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, login , password, name = None, surname = None, birthDate = None, hometown = None):

        user = self.model(
            login = login,
            name = name,
            surname = surname,
            birthDate = birthDate,
            hometown = hometown,
        )

        user.set_password(password)

        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, login , password, name = None, surname = None, birthDate = None, hometown = None):

        user = self.model(
            login = login,
            name = name,
            surname = surname,
            birthDate = birthDate,
            hometown = hometown,
        )

        user.set_password(password)

        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    login = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    birthDate = models.DateTimeField()
    hometown = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'login'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.name, self.surname)

    def get_short_name(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.name, self.surname)

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.name, self.surname)

    def auth(self, login, password):
        if login == self.login and password == self.password:
            return True
        return False
```

При попытке через `shell` создать объект этого класса(`s = User.objects.create('nrjshka@gmail.com', 'password','Maxim', 'Korolev', datetime.now(), 'Rybinsk')`) выдает следующую ошибку: 
[image]

P.S. Испробовал словари, кортежи и списки - ничего не помогает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подозреваю, что для create аргументы нужно передавать как ключевые, то есть в формате

`create(argname1=value1, argname2=value2, argname3=value3)`

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/189501)

Comment: @Anatol, похоже, автор вопроса с вами не согласен :)

Comment: такое тоже бывает